# How to assign a mocked abstract class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, abstract-class, nsubstitute

I know this question has sort of been asked but I believe I have a variant over the other question/answers.

I have this C# class:

```
public class  public CoreCycleTimer: MyAbstractClass
{
    public CoreCycleTimer()
    {
         if ( !Initialised ) 
        {
            Initialise( Path.Combine( settingsService.BaseDirectory, TimingDataFile ) );
        }
        WriteLine( "Initialised!" );
    }
}
```

My Abstract Class:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
    private FileStream fs;
    private StreamWriter stream;

    public bool Initialised { get; private set; }

    public void Initialise(
        string filePath )
    {
         fs = File.Open( filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite );
        stream = new StreamWriter( fs );
        Initialised = true;
    }

    public void WriteLine(
        string stringToWrite )
    {
        stream.WriteLine( stringToWrite );
        Flush();
    }
}
```

I am trying to test this by:

```
protected MyAbstractClass MockStreamWriterBuilderService;
protected CoreCycleTimer SUT;

protected override void Because()
{
    MockStreamWriterBuilderService = Substitute.For<MyAbstractClass>();
    SUT = new CoreCycleTimer();
}

[Test]
public void Then_An_IStreamWriterService_Is_Initialised()
{
    MockStreamWriterBuilderService.Received( 1 ).Initialise( Arg.Any<string>() );
}
```

But of course MockStreamWriterBuilderService is 'empty' (please refer to screenshot).  How can i approach this please?

NB:
I have abbreviated some of the code that deals with dispose, error-handling etc
[image]

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Though you indicated that you have abbreviated some of the code, what is left makes the code unable to compile.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for taking the time to reply.  I am a bit confused by your comment though.  Why can you not compile? I have removed the error handling and dispose. Not a real blocker is it?

Comment: Make `Initialise` method virtual so that it can be overridden and replaced with a stub

Comment: @Nkosi +1 + 1 thanks

Comment: I would also suggest you refactor this code to not make it so tightly coupled to IO implementation concerns.

Comment: @Nkosi Refactor I will also take a look at that.  In regards to using virtual/override for initialise... I am still unsure how I would implement that in my test class?

Comment: @mjwills hi thanks for asking. Yesit does

Comment: @mjwills Bad case of me describing things :) no, it is not null but the streams are not open. i will adjust question. Thank you